# Method to detect a click on a text in LibGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

How can I detect a click on a text using LibGdx? For example, I want the user to be able to click on the String `Show Highscore`. The problem I'm having is that I already implemented an if-statement, which states that if anything is clicked on, the game starts. What kind of method do I have to write now, so that the user can click on `Show Highscore`? I can change the if statement which uses the whole screen, if necessary. Thanks :)

```
public class MainMenuScreen implements Screen {

final FlappyWizardGame game;
OrthographicCamera camera;

String buttonHighscore = "Show Highscore";

public MainMenuScreen(FlappyWizardGame game) {
    this.game = game;

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);
    screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
}


@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.update();
    game.batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

    game.batch.begin();
    game.batch.draw(game.hermine, 0, 0, (int)(game.hermine.getWidth() * 0.25), (int)(game.hermine.getHeight() * 0.25));
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Welcome to Flappy Wizard!!! ", camera.viewportWidth / 3, camera.viewportHeight - 100);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, "Tap anywhere to begin!", camera.viewportWidth / 3, camera.viewportHeight - 150);
    game.font.draw(game.batch, buttonHighscore, camera.viewportWidth / 3, camera.viewportHeight - 200);


    if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must create a Rectangle around the Text:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
```

And then in your if statement check if the touch event is in the Rectangle:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
    if(rectangle.contains(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY())){
        openHighscore();
    } else{
        game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
        dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by Morchul is correct although for UI Screen you probably want to consider using LibGDX's Scene2D component. It allows you to easily create Label, button, menu and detect click event by adding listener to them.